# Does this topology verify second axiom of countability?

Tags: general-topology, real-numbers

I have $\mathbb{R}$ and $\tau= \{U \subset \mathbb{R} : 0 \in U, 1 \notin U\}\cup\{\emptyset, \mathbb{R}\}$, and I'm asked if this topology verifies the second axiom of countability. I believe it does not, because every set of the form $\{0, r\}$ with $r$ irrational is an open set that every base should have (as it can't be written as union of other open sets). Is my guess correct?

Comment: Yeah, I think your reasoning is correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. If $B$ is a base for $\tau$ and if $r\in\Bbb R$ \ $\{0,1\}$ then $\{0,r\}\in B.$ Otherwise there would be no $C$ such that $C\subset B\subset \tau$ and such that $\bigcup C=\{0,r\}$ because the only subsets of $\{0,r\}$ that are members of $\tau$ are $\{0,r\},\{0\},$ and $\emptyset.$

Another (similar) way: If $B$ is a base for a topology $\tau$ on a set $X$ and if $Y\subset X$ then $\{b\cap Y:b\in B\}$ is a base for the subspace topology $\{t\cap Y:t\in \tau\}$ on $Y.$ So if $Y$ is not 2nd-countable then $X$ is not 2nd-countable. In your question, with $X=\Bbb R$ and $Y=\Bbb R\setminus \{0,1\},$ the subspace $Y$ is discrete and uncountable, so $Y$ is not 2nd-countable, because for any $y\in Y,$ the set $\{y\}$ must belong to any base for $Y $.